# In Jest, my BeforeAll is being called half way through my test.concurrent.each

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

I'm having trouble figuring out what I'm doing wrong with some tests I'm doing here using ts-jest

In my test suite, I have a `beforeAll`, and `afterAll` and a `test.concurrent.each`
Here's the contents of the test file:

```
'use strict';

describe( 'Concurrent tests', () => {

beforeAll( async () => {
    await console.log( "Before All" );
    return true;
});

afterAll( () => {
    console.log( "After All" );
    return true;
});

test.concurrent.each( [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C",
    "D",
    "E",
    "F",
    "G",
    "H",
    "I",
    "J",
] )( 'Check %s', async ( value ) => {
    console.log( value );
});

});
```

When I run it, though, it goes `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `BeforeAll`, `F`, `G`, `H`, `I`, `J`, `AfterAll`

Here's the output from jest showing the order: https://hastebin.com/sabowitile.js

Any idea why BeforeAll isn't being called before everything else?

EDIT : If I split the tests up into individual tests, it works fine. Like this:

```
test( 'A', () => {
    console.log( "A" );
});
test( 'B', () => {
    console.log( "B" );
});
test( 'C', () => {
    console.log( "C" );
});
test( 'D', () => {
    console.log( "D" );
});
test( 'E', () => {
    console.log( "E" );
});
test( 'F', () => {
    console.log( "F" );
});
test( 'G', () => {
    console.log( "G" );
});
test( 'H', () => {
    console.log( "H" );
});
test( 'I', () => {
    console.log( "I" );
});
test( 'J', () => {
    console.log( "J" );
});
```

Comment: This is how `concurrent` works. It doesn't wait for before blocks.

Comment: Thanks - that makes (some kind of) sense. I had taken it that `concurrent` was concurrent with the other tests, but that `beforeAll` would still run before *all* tests, not just the ones that weren't marked as concurrent.